# Why is this time complexity O(total*n)?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, memoization

Namely I’m having trouble understanding why at worst case running that blue part takes *(total⋅n⋅2)+1* steps.

Here is the code of the function:
[image: Implementation]

The video this screenshot is from can be found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqlNzOcnCfs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not watch the video you linked. However, looking at the code, this looks like it's computing the number of distinct ways to making up the value `total` using coins in denominations given by the array `arr`.

The function `dp` essentially fills a dictionary `mem` with values. The dictionary `mem` is indexed by `total` and `i`. Over the recursive calls, `total` and `i` might (and will) become smaller. The new values taken by `total` will be in range `[0; total]`. The new values taken by `i` will be in range `[0; arr.length - 1]`.

Hence the number of possible different keys for the dictionary is at most `(total+1) * arr.length`

Calls to `dp` with a pair of values for `total` and `i` which is already in the dictionary do not result in further recursive calls. Hence the number of calls to `dp` which result in further recursive calls is at most `(total+1) * arr.length`.

Since each call to `dp` results in at most 2 further recursive calls, the total number of calls to `dp` is at most `2 * (total+1) * arr.length`. Which is `O(total * arr.length)`. Which I assume is what you call `O(total * n)`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand the idea from this answer